# dynamically add product custom options magento

Tags: php, magento

i am a newbie to magento.
I have added a couple of custom options for a product that i added from the backend like name , address, email.

So it looks like this now :

```
Item 1

    Name : [textbox]
    Email : [textbox]
    Address : [textarea]
```

Now what i want to do is to dynamically add custom options. 
For that there will be 2 buttons, "Add an item" and "Remove an item".

So when i click "Add an item" the result should look like this:

```
Item 1

    Name : [textbox]
    Email : [textbox]
    Address : [textarea]

Item 2

    Name : [textbox]
    Email : [textbox]
    Address : [textarea]
```

When i click "Remove an item" it should remove an item.

How can i implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If It is completely Dynamic you can create  a form on product detail page For Adding and Removing Item you need to create using jQuery.

For Managing in order if you add this data in quote then it will be managed in whole order.

So for adding Dynamically created option you need to create a module.

I have created a module **Personlization** with namespace **Tech** that will add `intials` Custom option if you have this input box avialable on product details page form.

So before creating a module add new form element in Product detail page Named `intials`.

In `Tech/Personlization/etc/config.xml` File you need to code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Tech_Personlization>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</Tech_Personlization>
</modules>
<global>
  <models>
  <personlization>
    <class>Tech_Personlization_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>personlization_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </personlization>
</models>
<events>        
    <catalog_product_load_after>
        <observers>
            <personlization>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>personlization/observer</class>
                <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
            </personlization>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>
    <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        <observers>
            <personlization>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>personlization/observer</class>
                <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
            </personlization>
        </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
</events>
</global>
</config>
```

Also you need to create a observe `Tech/Personlization/Model/Observer.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
class Tech_Personlization_Model_Observer {
public function catalogProductLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();

    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add' || $action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_updateItemOptions'){          
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();                   

                $array = array();
                $array['intials']  = $post['intials'];

                if ($options = $array)
                {                       
                    $additionalOptions = array();
                    if ($additionalOption = $product->getCustomOption('additional_options'))
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
                        }                           
                    foreach ($options as $key => $value)
                        {
                            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                                'label' => $key,
                                'value' => $value,
                            );
                        }

                    $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
                }
    }
}

public function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quoteItem = $observer->getItem();
    if ($additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) 
    {
        $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
        $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
        $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
    }                       
}

}
```

Hope this Help !!

Comment: thanks...but the observer is not firing when i click "add to cart"

Comment: Its working at my end. Please check observer name. Enable error reporting.

Comment: actually i have created some text fields in the addtocart.phtml in the product details page before the "add to cart button" but its not working. turned on error reporting but no luck

Comment: First Debug in cart controller add action if your custom fields are coming there or not in submitted form data. If it is okay then try debug in observer using log function or die.

Comment: the post data is coming in the cart controller.

Comment: this means that you have not created module correctly. Please debug your module carefully.

Comment: in the cartcontroller add action this is the event that is getting fired - checkout_cart_add_product_complete. but in our config file we have mentioned catalog_product_load_after as the event name. is this correct?

Comment: one more thing.. i have to upload an image in the form. could you pls tell me how i should go about it? googling didn't help.

Comment: you can upload image from observer and link with one custom option. but you have to manage it everywhere manully as I undersand. glad solution worked for you. give a upvote to answer :)

Comment: thanks and sorry i dont have the minimum rep to upvote the answer so +1